# Concatenate two or more fields in SOQL

Tags: soql

Is that possible in SOQL to concatenate two fields?

```
SELECT id,name,Description, Make__r.Name + '  ' +    
       Model__r.Name + ' ' + Model_Year__c  FROM my_custom_object__c
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to do that sort of processing after your query.

```
My_Custom_Object__c record; // = some record in your query results
String makeAndModel = record.Make__r.Name + ' ' + record.Model__r.Name;
```

However, you could put it together in a formula and query that:

`Formula`:

```
Make__r.Name + ' ' + Model__r.Name
```

`SOQL`:

```
SELECT Make_and_Model__c FROM My_Custom_Object__c
```

Answer (score 0):

No, data cannot be manipulated directly in a SOQL query. You would have to query the fields separately and then concatenate them on your own.